# How to get list items in a for x in range loop to show on tkinter frame

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tkinter, function

This is a portion of the original code. I don't get any error messages but nothing seems to show when I open the Calendar frame. I had the submit(self) function print out in python the value of Control.counter when it is called, and nothing shows when the Control.counter value is more than 0.

```
class Setup_Info(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="white")

        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        title2 = tk.Label(self, text="Setup Information", font=LARGE_FONT, background="white")
        title2.place(relx=0.25, y=0.00, relheight=0.2, relwidth=0.5)

        self.number = tk.Entry(self)
        self.number.place(relx=0.2, y=140, relheight=0.05)

        question1 = tk.Label(self, text="Name of medication:", font=FONT, background="white")
        question1.place(relx=0.2, y=200, relheight=0.05)
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry1.place(relx=0.2, y=240, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.2)

        question2 = tk.Label(self, text="When it was prescribed:", font=FONT, background="white")
        question2.place(relx=0.2, y=300, relheight=0.05)
        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry2.place(relx=0.2, y=340, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.2)

        question3 = tk.Label(self, text="When you stop the medication:", font=FONT, background="white")
        question3.place(relx=0.2, y=400, relheight=0.05)
        self.entry3 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry3.place(relx=0.2, y=440, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.2)

        question4 = tk.Label(self, text="How many times in a day do you take it:", font=FONT, background="white")
        question4.place(relx=0.2, y=500, relheight=0.05)
        self.entry4 = ttk.Combobox(self)
        self.entry4.config(values = ('1','2','3'))
        self.entry4.place(relx=0.45, y=540, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.2)

        enter = tk.Button(self, text="Enter", font=LARGE_FONT, background="white",
                          command=self.submit)
        enter.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.2, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.2)

        enter2 = tk.Button(self, text="Enter", font=LARGE_FONT, background="white",
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Calendar))
        enter2.pack()

        Setup_Info.list1=[]
        Setup_Info.list2=[]
        Setup_Info.list3=[]
        Setup_Info.list4=[]

    def submit(self):
        print(self.number.get())
        Control.counter += int(self.number.get())
        print(Control.counter)
        entry1=self.entry1.get()
        entry2=self.entry2.get()
        entry3=self.entry3.get()
        entry4=self.entry4.get()
        Setup_Info.list1.append(entry1)
        Setup_Info.list2.append(entry2)
        Setup_Info.list3.append(entry3)
        Setup_Info.list4.append(entry4)
        print(Setup_Info.list1)
        print(Setup_Info.list2)
        print(Setup_Info.list3)
        print(Setup_Info.list4)



class Calendar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="white")

        if Control.counter > 0:
            display_info()

    def display_info():
        for x in range(Control.counter):
            self.medicine1 = tk.Label(self, text=(Setup_Info.list1[x]), font=LARGE_FONT, bg="white")
            self.medicine1.pack()

            self.medicine2 = tk.Label(self, text=(Setup_Info.list2[x]), font=LARGE_FONT, bg="white")
            self.medicine1.pack()
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging to see if the problem is that the calendar frame isn't showing, or that the frame is showing but the internal widgets are not? It looks like the problem possibly is in the `show_frame` function, but you haven't shown that code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `Calendar` class is instantiated when the program starts up. At that point in time, `Control.counter` is zero (I'm assuming) because the user hasn't had a chance to enter anything yet. Thus, the frame is empty.

When you go to show the frame, you don't recreate the frame, or reinitialize the contents, so the window will be empty.

You will need to modify your code to either create the class on demand when you need it, or directly call the `display_info` method immediately before you show the frame.

Answer (score 0):

for one it seems you are creating class variables in Setup_info every time you initialize an Setup_info object, it is quite possible the lists are reset to empty every time one is created but I can't be certain based on the code you have provided, try removing this from the **init**()

```
    Setup_Info.list1=[]
    Setup_Info.list2=[]
    Setup_Info.list3=[]
    Setup_Info.list4=[]
```

and putting their definitions in the class itself:

```
class Setup_Info(tk.Frame):
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    list3=[]
    list4=[]
    def __init__ ...
```

your problem is clearly linked to what ever Control is, so without the code for that as well there isn't much I can do for you...